# Android: How to handle bluetooth connection between android and pc

Tags: android, eclipse, bluetooth

How can I handle a connection between Android and a PC with Bluetooth.
Android Device send and Pc receive.
PC is a Windows 7 64x Bit machine.
Android Device = Android 4.1.2
Would be happy of any Help.

Comment: I understand you're new to SO but this is far too vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you will need to make your PC bluetooth compatible. If it already has native bluetooth support, you're on the right track. Then all you need to do is write the connections as described  [here in the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html). What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: My PC is equiped with an Bluetooth Usb stick.
With my Android System I can pair both device and can send a txt File but i don´t get it work in my Programm.
I test it with an Intent but in the pop up screen it only shows my Email clients no Bluetooth. Thanks for Help

Comment: What is this Intent and pop up screen you speak of?